# Given a function, find values of when it is equal to $100$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

**Question:** Let $f(n) = 2n - [\frac{(1 + \sqrt{8n – 7})}{2}]$ for each positive integer, where $[x]$ is denoted for the largest integer less than or equal to $x$ for any real number $x$. Find the sum of all possible value(s) $n$ such that $f(n) = 100$.

**My solution:**

If $f(n) = 100$ then $2n - [\frac{1 + \sqrt{8n – 7}}{2}] = 100$. It is also known that $[x] = \lfloor{x}\rfloor$, so I will be using $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ throughout the rest of my answer.

First of all, $2n - [\frac{1 + \sqrt{8n – 7}}{2}] = 2n - \lfloor(2 + \frac{\sqrt{8n – 7}}{2})\rfloor$.

So, since $2n - \lfloor(2 + \frac{\sqrt{8n – 7}}{2})\rfloor = 100$, and $\lfloor{x}\rfloor \approx x$, we want $2n - (2 + \frac{\sqrt{8n – 7}}{2}) \approx 100$

Solving this equation, we get $2 + \frac{\sqrt{8n - 7}}{2} \approx 100 - 2n$. So, $\sqrt{8n - 7} \approx 196 - 4n.$ Since $\sqrt{8n - 7}$ is positive, $196 - 4n$ is also positive. So, $n > 49$.

Testing values of $n$, we see that $n = 55$ works. If $n > 55$, then $f(n) > 100$. This is because $2n$ grows much bigger than $\sqrt{8n - 7}$ when $n > 55$.

Hence, there is only one value of $n$, which is $55$, so the answer is $\boxed{55}$.

Could anyone review my solution for a better solution or if there are any mistakes in my solution? Feel free to write a better answer in the answers section and thanks in advance!

Comment: If $n=55$ then $\sqrt {8n-7}=\sqrt{433}=20.808652$.  So the floor term yields $\lfloor (1 +10.4)\rfloor=11$, and $2\times 55-11=99$, not $100$.  Or have I misread something?

Comment: The only solution I find is $n=55.5$ which, of course, is not an integer.

Comment: @lulu oops there was a mistake in my latex, I changed the question

Comment: Ok, for that version I agree that $n=55$ is the only solution (even if you include half integers as possibilities).

Comment: @lulu thanks :)

Comment: @lulu is there a better solution to the problem?

Comment: Oh, I just searched.  I mean, it's kind of obvious that $50$ is too small and $60$ is too big.  And it is clear that the answer must be an integer or half an integer.  So there are only a handful of cases, and I just checked all of them (meaning I had my computer check all of them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2n- \left\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}2\right\rfloor= 100$$

$$2n-100 =\left\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}2\right\rfloor $$

$$  \frac{\sqrt{8n-7}-1}2\le 2n-100 \le  \frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}{2}$$

$$4n-200-1 \le \sqrt{8n-7} \le 4n-200 + 1$$

$$(4n-201)^2 \le 8n-7 \le (4n-199)^2$$

The first inequality is satisfied for $$46 \le n \le 55$$

and the second inequality is satisfied by $$n \le 45 \lor n \ge 55$$

$n=55$ is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution!